# What is this slot?

Tags: laptop, motherboard

So, I opened up my laptop the other day to pop-in an SSD and new HDD, and found this little slot open:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/v8NSZFY.jpg]

Any idea what the slot under the RAM is for? I think it might be for an internet card but I have no idea.

I have looked around a bit, and tried comparing images I found online, but I haven't found anything that matches this yet.

Comment: What is the laptop make/model?

Comment: it's an ACER v3-772G (there's a lot of those, so you're looking for the one with an i7 4702MQ and a gtx850m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be Mini PCI Express (shown in a picture at [Wikipedia's a ticle on PCI: "Mini PCI" section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI#Mini_PCI))?

Comment: Looked at the specifications of Mini PCIe and compared some models, with their sizes and pins, and that is what matches! thanks!